# Why are my python models giving me problems for PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to store a JSON object in a postgreSQL database. I was able to do this when I had just one Model, but when I added a second table to my database and a second model to my code, I got a long error message that reads as follows:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Type annotation for "FieldData.field" can't be correctly interpreted for Annotated Declarative Table form.  ORM annotations should normally make use of the `Mapped[]` generic type, or other ORM-compatible generic type, as a container for the actual type, which indicates the intent that the attribute is mapped. Class variables that are not intended to be mapped by the ORM should use ClassVar[].  To allow Annotated Declarative to disregard legacy annotations which don't use Mapped[] to pass, set "**allow_unmapped** = True" on the class or a superclass this class. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/zlpr)

My code is as follows:

```
#In dal.py...

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

DB_USER="user"
DB_PASSWORD="password"
DB_SERVER="123.456.789.0"
DB_PORT=5432
DB_NAME="db"

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_SERVER}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}"

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

connection = engine.connect()

#session establishes converstion with db
PlantSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
FieldSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

#base class stores a catlog of classes and mappsed tables
Base = declarative_base()
```

```
#In schemas.py...

from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List

class Plant(BaseModel):
    date: datetime
    temperature: float
    moisture: int
    conductivity: int
    ph: float
    nitrogen: int
    phosphorus: int
    potassium: int
    plantid: str
        
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        
class Field(BaseModel):
    field: str
    crop_type: str
    color: str
    acerage: float
    points: List[str]
    spike_x: float
    spike_y: float
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

```
# in models.py...

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import TIMESTAMP, ARRAY
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import dal

class PlantData(dal.Base):
    __tablename__ = "planttable"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    
    date = Column(TIMESTAMP, primary_key=True)
    temperature = Column(Float)
    moisture = Column(Integer) 
    conductivity = Column(Integer)
    ph = Column(Float)
    nitrogen = Column(Integer)
    phosphorus = Column(Integer)
    potassium = Column(Integer)
    plantid = Column(String)
    
    # dal.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=dal.engine)
    
class FieldData(dal.Base):
    __tablename__ = "field_data"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}
    
    field: Column(String, primary_key=True)
    crop_type: Column(String)
    color: Column(String)
    acerage: Column(Float)
    points: Column(ARRAY(String))
    spike_x: Column(Float)
    spike_y: Column(Float)
    
dal.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=dal.engine)
```

What I had previously, before I added the second table and model, is what you see above, but without:
The class 'FieldData' in models.py,The class 'Field' in schemas.py, and 'FieldSessionLocal' in dal.py

I only got this error after I made changes to models.py, so I believe the problem lies in there, but I am not sure what to do from here

Comment: You're using colons instead of equal signs in `FieldData`

Comment: Yep, that was it! I was working on this problem for over an hour. If that isn't coding in a nutshell I don't know what is